# PySpark - how to convert code pandas to pyspark - nested when

Tags: python, pyspark

how are you?

So, I need to convert some code written in pandas to PySpark, but so far I'm still having some problems, I've tried using PySpark's function `when`, but the result is wrong, can you help me? This is very simple and I'm starting with PySpark

```
df = df.assign(new_col=np.where(df.col1.isnull() 
                              ,np.where(df.col2.isnull(), df.col3,
                                    np.where(df.col3.isnull(), df.col2,((df.col2+df.col3/2))
                                            ),df.col1)))
```

The main goal here is to understand how to use nested `when`.

I thank you in advance!!

Comment: Sample data would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Without sample input output hard to know what to expect especially given your code does not run in pandas either. Multiple when statements should replace nested np.where statement.

Code below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn('newcol1', when(col('col1').isNull()&col('col2').isNull(), col('col3'))).withColumn('newcol1', when(col('col3').isNull()&col('col1').isNotNull(), col('col2')).otherwise(col('col3'))).withColumn('newcol1', when(col('col3').isNull()&col('col2').isNull(), col('col1')).otherwise(col('newcol1'))).show()
```